# how to merge two signals with SampleOn in Elm

Tags: elm, elm-signal

I try to merge two signals. One is Mouse.clicks and another is Keyboard.space.

- On clicks, I should get a Signal(Int,Int) from Mouse.position as return value
- On space, I should get something different so I can identify different signal is triggered.

My idea is:

```elm
type Event = Click | Space

mergedSignal : Signal Event
mergedSignal = 
  let
    clickSignal = map (\event -> Click) Mouse.clicks
    timeoutSignal = map (\event -> Space) Keyboard.space
  in
    merge clickSignal timeoutSignal
```

and get position somehow:

```elm
positionOnClickSignal:Signal (Int,Int)
positionOnClickSignal = sampleOn Mouse.clicks Mouse.position
```

Obviously, it is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want the mouse position to carry over as part of the event. In that case, you could redefine `Event` as

```elm
type Event
  = Click (Int, Int)
  | Space
```

Inside your `mergedSignal`, the `clickSignal` is currently just checking for `Mouse.clicks` but based on your description and other example, I think you actually want that to be based off `positionOnclickSignal`, which gives you a `Signal (Int, Int)`, and using that, you can now populate the `(Int, Int)` portion of the `Click (Int, Int)` event like this:

```elm
clickSignal =
  map Click positionOnClickSignal
```

You'll notice that I took out the parenthesis in the above. That is more idiomatic for Elm, because `Click` is in essence a function that takes one `(Int, Int)` parameter, which will be passed in from the map function. It could have easily been written like this:

```elm
clickSignal =
  map (\pos -> Click pos) positionOnClickSignal
```

Now, if you're just trying to see some debug text of this on screen, a quick and easy way to go about that is to use `show` from the `Graphics.Element` package.

```elm
import Graphics.Element exposing (show)

main =
  map (show << toString) mergedSignal
```

That will give you some debug text shown as the only thing on the page, and you could easily toss it up on http://elm-lang.org/try for testing.